# Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]?

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite

I am using SQLite and Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.20.Final but I get the following error.

```
ago 21, 2020 10:47:09 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.20.Final
ago 21, 2020 10:47:09 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
ago 21, 2020 10:47:10 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at com.abigsite.facturationsystem.config.GenerateTables.main(GenerateTables.java:12)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: max size attribute is mandatory
    at org.hibernate.agroal.internal.AgroalConnectionProvider.configure(AgroalConnectionProvider.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: max size attribute is mandatory
    at io.agroal.api.configuration.supplier.AgroalConnectionPoolConfigurationSupplier.validate(AgroalConnectionPoolConfigurationSupplier.java:237)
    at io.agroal.api.configuration.supplier.AgroalConnectionPoolConfigurationSupplier.get(AgroalConnectionPoolConfigurationSupplier.java:278)
    at io.agroal.api.configuration.supplier.AgroalConnectionPoolConfigurationSupplier.get(AgroalConnectionPoolConfigurationSupplier.java:25)
    at io.agroal.api.configuration.supplier.AgroalDataSourceConfigurationSupplier.connectionPoolConfiguration(AgroalDataSourceConfigurationSupplier.java:53)
    at io.agroal.api.configuration.supplier.AgroalPropertiesReader.readProperties(AgroalPropertiesReader.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.agroal.internal.AgroalConnectionProvider.configure(AgroalConnectionProvider.java:81)
    ... 22 more
```

I have the following configuration in my hibernate xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.SQLiteDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.sqlite.JDBC</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlite:mydb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>

        <mapping class="model.Role" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I am doing a simple example the following class is the entity that I am using:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private byte roleId;

    public Role() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public byte getRoleId() {
        return roleId;
    }

    public void setRoleId(byte roleId) {
        this.roleId = roleId;
    }

}
```

And finally I have this class that takes care of persisting

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.abigsite.facturationsystem.model.Role;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SessionFactory session = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        Session s = session.openSession();

        Transaction t = s.beginTransaction();

        Role role = new Role();
        s.save(role);
        t.commit();
    }
}
```

The error occurs on the line:

```
SessionFactory session = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

The location of the database is verified, in addition, the SQLite JDBC .jar is used in the dependencies, on the other hand, the correct dialect is being used, the same with library

Comment: You may have tagged this question with wrong tag. Your code is using Hibernate, not NHibernate :-)

Comment: Edited, sorry I didn't realize.